# Define Haskell type constructor equality?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, pattern-synonyms

I'm not meaning as a member of Eq. My code:

```
data Race = Terran | Zerg | Protoss deriving (Eq, Show, Read);

data MU = MU Race Race deriving (Eq, Show);
```

In this case I define for instance `(MU Terran Zerg)`. I want to create a data constructor `TvZ` which is essentially identical in all aspects for intance so I can match a function pattern:

```
foo TvZ = ...
```

instead of having to do

```
foo (MU Terran Zerg) = ...
```

Which you can't do if you assign it to a variable as in `tvZ = (MU Terran Zerg)`

Another thing I want to do is making short forms as in making the type constructor `T` and `Terran` identical.

Last thing, medivac speed boost needs a minor nerf I feel.

Comment: Do you want to differentiate between TvZ and ZvT? Also, what do you gain from matching `TvZ` over `(MU Terran Zerg)`?

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: What you're asking for has been proposed a few times under the name "pattern synonyms", see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/PatternSynonyms) and [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms), but I haven't heard of any plans to implement it (yet).

Comment: What I gain from the short form is that it's shorter and cleaner, less room for typing errors. The very reason we tend to do pi = 3.14159265359 oce and then get it over with, short is good, leaves less room for typing errors.

Comment: Have you considered using view patterns as a poor substitute?

Comment: [SHE](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/patsy.html) offers a prototype implementation of pattern synonyms: they're so simple a mere preprocessor can handle it. It's your basic definitional abstraction, but for the pattern language as well as the expression language. All the usual motivations for definitional abstraction apply. View patterns are often mentioned as a candidate alternative in this context, a position which is its own punishment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're asking for is called a "pattern synonym", and has been proposed multiple times. It is currently not implemented. You can view the proposals [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms), [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5144), and a bunch of other places (links courtesy of hammar).

However, as a solution, this works just as well:

```
foo (MU Terran Zerg) = ...
foo (MU Zerg Terran) = foo $ MU Terran Zerg
```

and will effectively achieve the same thing, even if it doesn't look as nice.

Comment: It seems Pattern Synonyms are what I'm looking for yeah, apart from that I also wish to be able to call a function as `foo TvZ` rather than `foo (MU Terran Zerg)` Not sure if the proposal for pattern synonyms also allows that.

Answer (score 6):

First try, use the following pattern (I'm assuming that `MU Terran Terran` and other self-relations are allowed.):

```
foo (MU Terran Terran)   = ...
foo (MU Terran Zerg)     = ...
foo (MU Terran Protoss)  = ...
foo (MU Zerg Zerg)       = ...
foo (MU Zerg Protoss)    = ...
foo (MU Protoss Protoss) = ...
foo (MU x y) = foo (MU y x)
```

You have to be very careful with functions defined like that, because if you don't get the cases to be exhaustive it's an infinite loop.

Second try: I had a shot at generalizing the pattern, and the best I came up with is this, which is barely any better:

```
forceSymmetric :: (MU -> Maybe r) -> MU -> r
forceSymmetric f = \p -> case f p of
                          Nothing -> fromJust (f (swap p))
                          Just r -> r

foo (MU Terran Terran)   = Just ...
foo (MU Terran Zerg)     = Just ...
foo (MU Terran Protoss)  = Just ...
foo (MU Zerg Zerg)       = Just ...
foo (MU Zerg Protoss)    = Just ...
foo (MU Protoss Protoss) = Just ...
foo (MU x y)             = Nothing
```

This has the virtue that you'd gen an error instead of an infinite loop if you mess up.

Third, deeper try: the heart of the problem is that you want **symmetry**.  Let's forget that `MU` is a constructor, and just treat it as a function.  You want it to obey this symmetry law:

```
MU a b == MU b a
```

By `==` I don't necessarily mean the `Eq` type class here, but rather **mutual substitutibility**; substituting one expression for the other should not affect the meaning of any program.

Well, algebraic data types don't have that property, period.  For an algebraic data type constructor like `MU`, `MU a b == MU c d` if and only if `a == b` and `c == d`.  So if you want to make it impossible for any function to distinguish between `MU Terran Zerg` and `MU Zerg Terran`, you need to make the `MU` type abstract, so that its users cannot see its internal representation.

The formula for number of combinations of *n* items taken *r* at a time, with duplicates allowed, is `factorial (n + r - 1) / (factorial r * factorial (n - 1))`; for `n = 3` and `r = 2`, this is 6 combinations.  So what we want is to define a type `MU` that has only six possible values, a function `toMU :: Race -> Race -> MU` such that `mu a b == mu b a`, and a function `fromMU :: MU -> (Race, Race)` such that `uncurry toMU . fromMU == id`.  The easiest way I can think of doing this is to use sorted tuples:

```
data Race = Terran | Zerg | Protoss deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Ord);

data SortedPair a = SP a a  -- The constructor here needs to be private

makeSortedPair :: Ord a => a -> a -> SortedPair a
makeSortedPair a b | a < b     = SP a b
                   | otherwise = SP b a

breakSortedPair :: SortedPair a a -> (a, a)
breakSortedPair (SP a b) = (a, b)

type MU = SortedPair Race

toMU :: Race -> Race -> MU
toMU = makeSortedPair

fromMU :: MU -> (Race, Race)
fromMU = breakSortedPair
```

Now you're guaranteed that `fromMU` can produce `(Terran, Zerg)` but not `(Zerg, Terran)`, so you can leave out the final "catch-all" cases from the first two proposals above.  (The compiler doesn't know anything about this, however, so it will still complain about non-exhaustive patterns.)

Comment: Very extensive, but completely not an answer to what I'm asking. I'm also not sure where you get the symmetry from. TvZ \= ZvT here. I'm not sure what exactly you are answering here, but it isn't remotely related to what I'm asking. What I'm asking for are apparently called Pattern Synonyms which are yet to be implemented.

Comment: @user28062, As data Race derived from Ord class its elements (Terran, Zergl, Protoss) can be compared. Then, as Zergl > Terran, (because Zergl is declared after Terran in the data Race declaration), ZvT become TvZ. This is achieve by the use of makeSortedPair into the toMu function. Here the idea is, as the type system is not enough expressive to achieve what you are asking, sacundim propose a workaround based on function, which replace the use of type constructor on left-side, by interfacing  isomorphic's function on the right-side. IMO I find this pretty clever. Of course, if I've got it.

Comment: @zurgl, nice, but that wasn't the issue I was dealing with at all. I didn't want ZvT to be the same as TvZ, I wanted to pattern match with `foo TvZ = ...` rather than having to use `foo (MU Terran Zerg) = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with GHC 7.8, you can use [pattern synonyms](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PatternSynonyms), a new language extension aimed, among others, exactly for this use case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern TvZ :: MU
pattern TvZ = MU Terran Zerg
```

This will allow you to use `TvZ` both in pattern context (i.e. matching) and expression context (i.e. construction of a new `MU` value).